# Modifying State in Flink's Aggregate Function within a Windowed Operation

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-checkpoint

I'm working on a Flink application where I'm using an aggregate function over a window. I've been able to successfully read the state of its outputs using the provided APIs.

However, in my specific use case, I also need to be able to stop the processing, retrieve and modify the state, and then resume processing without resetting checkpoints. Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't provide any examples for such use cases.

This is how the aggregator and window function is used:

```scala
eventStream
    .keyBy(_.key)
    .window(TumblingTimeWindow.of(5.minutes))
    .aggregate(new Aggregator, new PostAggregatorWindowFunction)
    .uid("aggregate-every-5-minutes")
```

Then I run separately:

```scala
val readerStream = SavepointReader.read(env, checkpointFile, backend)
    .window(TumblingTimeWindow.of(5.minutes))
    .aggregate(
    "aggregate-every-5-minutes",
    new Aggregator,
    new WindowStateReader // Extends WindowReaderFunction and outputs (KEY, CurrentAggregate)
  )

val transformation = OperatorTransformation
    .bootstrapWith(readerStream)
    .keyBy(_._1) // Keying by first entry of tuple (KEY, CurrentAggregate)
    .window(TumblingTimeWindow.of(5.minutes))
    .aggregate(???, ???) // How do we define these? And how do we set their state?

SavepointWriter.fromExistingSavepoint(env, checkpointFile, backend)
    .removeOperator(OperatorIdentifier.forUid("aggregate-every-5-minutes"))
    .addOperator(OperatorIdentifier.forUid("aggregate-every-5-minutes", transformation))
    .write(outputFile)
```

Could someone please guide me on how I can achieve this in Flink 1.17? Any code snippets or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide context for why you think you need to interrupt processing?

Comment: @kkrugler I added some code snippets and did some rewordings that I think will better explain what I have in mind.

Comment: Using the State Processor APIs is normally for solving a one-time problem, but it sounds like you plan on making this part of your regular workflow...why?